# Retrieving database column using JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a database consist of 4 columns (id-symbol-name-contractnumber). All 4 columns with their data are being displayed on the user interface using JSON.

There is a function which is responisble to add new column to the database e.g (countrycode).

The coulmn is added successfully to the database BUT not able to show the new added coulmn in the user interface.

Below is my code that is displaying the columns.

Can you help me?

table.php

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxmenu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.selection.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.filter.js"></script>        
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxdata.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/gettheme.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    // prepare the data
    var theme = getDemoTheme();

    var source =
    {
        datatype: "json",
    datafields: [
                 { name: 'id' },
                 { name: 'symbol' },
                 { name: 'name' },

                 { name: 'contractnumber' }
            ],
        url: 'data.php',
        filter: function()
        {
            // update the grid and send a request to the server.
            $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('updatebounddata', 'filter');
        },
        cache: false
    };      
    var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

    // initialize jqxGrid
    $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
    {       
        source: dataAdapter,
        width: 670,
        theme: theme,
        showfilterrow: true,
        filterable: true,
        columns: [
            { text: 'id', datafield: 'id', width: 200 },
            { text: 'symbol', datafield: 'symbol', width: 200 },
            { text: 'name', datafield: 'name', width: 100 },
            { text: 'contractnumber', filtertype: 'list', datafield: 'contractnumber' }
        ]
    });
    });
</script>
       </head>
           <body class='default'>
        <div id="jqxgrid"></div>
        </div>
            </body>
       </html>
```

data.php

```
      <?php
#Include the db.php file
include('db.php');
#Connect to the database
//connection String
$connect = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password)
or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
//Select The database
$bool = mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $connect);
if ($bool === False){
   print "can't find $database";
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM pricelist";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die("SQL Error 1: " . mysql_error());
$orders = array();
// get data and store in a json array
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $orders[] = array(
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'symbol' => $row['symbol'],
        'name' => $row['name'],

        'contractnumber' => $row['contractnumber']

      );
}

echo json_encode($orders);
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new column to your DB, you will have to somehow update the UI, too. In order to do that you will have to add a new datafield to the datafields array of the source object and update the Grid's columns by setting the columns property.

$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({columns: newColumnsArray});

Comment: can you guide me how to do

Answer (score 0):

You said that the column "contrycode" was properly appended to the `pricelist` table? So, it doen't look very difficult to get the column values in `$order` and to display them as JSON. Without looking to much in your code, I would start by...

```
# in your PHP
$orders[] = array(
    'countrycode' = $row['countrycode'],
    'id' => $row['id'],
  ...
```

and:

```
# in your JS
    columns: [
        { text: 'countrycode', datafield: 'countrycode', width: 2 },
        { text: 'id', datafield: 'id', width: 200 },
  ...
```

Comment: can you looking into my code .The coulmn is added successfully to the database BUT not able to show the new added coulmn in the user interface.

Answer (score 0):

For php side it should be easy to make array for dynamic fields if you use loop inside while.

```
$orders = array(); $i  = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $orders[$i] = array();
    foreach($row as $col => $value) {
        $orders[$i][$col] = $value; 
    }
    $i++;
}
```

However for jqgrid You must find solution for yourself to show dynamic columns.